# GNU gdb can not step into template functions (OS X Mavericks)

Tags: c++, templates, gdb, osx-mavericks

I have installed `gdb 7.7` (from GNU sources) under OS X Mavericks (10.9.2). I codesigned it, so it works fine whenever I debug a `c++` file that does not contain templates. However, it is unable to step into template functions (can step into regular functions, but just fails to step into templated ones). When I type `step` command in a debugging session, it just steps over the function, as if the debugging symbols are not present for the template function. My template function is not even a member function, is just a simple function defined inside the `main.cpp`.

I compile my program with `g++ -g -O0 main.cpp` (I use `g++4.8.2` from `macports` and not `clang++`), even tried `-fno-inline`, still same behaviour, cannot step into template functions. Is this a `gdb` known problem under OS X Mavericks?  Or, can anyone reproduce the bug?

my code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> // template
void f(T x)
{
    std::cout << "In f:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

void g() // non-template
{
    std::cout << "It works here!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Exiting g()..." << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    f<double>(12.3); // gdb does not step into f()
    g(); // gdb steps into g()
}
```

Can not step in `f` after a breakpoint at `f<double>(12.3)`.
If `f()` is a regular function, such as `g()` in my code, then it steps into.
Thanks!

Update: `gdb` works as it should under any other OS, such as `linux/windows/solaris`. It seems to be  a problem related to OS X.

```
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x0000000100000d62 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000100000d63 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100000d66 <+4>: movabs $0x402899999999999a,%rax
   0x0000000100000d70 <+14>:    movq   %rax,%xmm0
   0x0000000100000d75 <+19>:    callq  0x100000e44
   0x0000000100000d7a <+24>:    callq  0x100000d0c <g()>
   0x0000000100000d7f <+29>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000100000d84 <+34>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100000d85 <+35>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Now we set a breakpoint at the entry of `main()`

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000d66: file src/templated_bug.cpp, line 22.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/vlad/template_gdb_bug/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at src/templated_bug.cpp:22
22      f<double>(12.3);
(gdb) s
In f:
12.3
23      g();
(gdb) s
g () at src/templated_bug.cpp:16
16      cout<<"It works here!"<<endl;
(gdb) s
It works here!
17      cout<<"Exiting g()..."<<endl;
(gdb) s
Exiting g()...
18  }
(gdb) s
main () at src/templated_bug.cpp:24
24  }
(gdb) s
[Inferior 1 (process 50945) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

As you can see, it does not step inside `f()` but steps inside `g()`. Moreover,

```
(gdb) disassemble f
No symbol "f" in current context.
```

However, for another function `g()` that is non-template, the symbols are loaded and I can disassemble it.

```
(gdb) disassemble g
Dump of assembler code for function g():
   0x0000000100000d0c <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000100000d0d <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100000d10 <+4>: lea    0x193(%rip),%rsi        # 0x100000eaa
   0x0000000100000d17 <+11>:    mov    0x2ea(%rip),%rax        # 0x100001008
   0x0000000100000d1e <+18>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000100000d21 <+21>:    callq  0x100000e5c
   0x0000000100000d26 <+26>:    mov    0x2e3(%rip),%rdx        # 0x100001010
   0x0000000100000d2d <+33>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x0000000100000d30 <+36>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000100000d33 <+39>:    callq  0x100000e4a
   0x0000000100000d38 <+44>:    lea    0x17a(%rip),%rsi        # 0x100000eb9
   0x0000000100000d3f <+51>:    mov    0x2c2(%rip),%rax        # 0x100001008
   0x0000000100000d46 <+58>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000100000d49 <+61>:    callq  0x100000e5c
   0x0000000100000d4e <+66>:    mov    0x2bb(%rip),%rdx        # 0x100001010
   0x0000000100000d55 <+73>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x0000000100000d58 <+76>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000100000d5b <+79>:    callq  0x100000e4a
   0x0000000100000d60 <+84>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000100000d61 <+85>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: does it step into if you use an integer type? (I have no access to OS X to try this)

Comment: no, the type does not matter. I used a type as I thought `gdb` may have a problem with type deduction... As I said, in `linux` everything runs as it should run. Damn OS X...

Comment: can you post output of "disassemble main" and "b main"?

Comment: Posted now at the bottom of my question.

Comment: how did you install GDB? Via clit or with the standard tools (custom)

Comment: Via all possible methods :) I tried the `macports` version first, then, thinking it's a problem with the precompiled version, I did compile it from source. Still same issue. And it happens on all machines that run OS X Mavericks.

Comment: I think I know at least what's happening, the debugger does not find the symbols for `f()`. If I add another function (non-template), then the symbols are loaded, I can disassemble it and step into it. Why is this is beyond my understanding...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In seems there is an issues with the **step into** command at MacOS port of gdb. As workaround you could set breakpoint at the function start to step into the template function:

```
(gdb) b f<double>
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1000015ab: file ./gdb_tmpl.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/vershov/tmp/tests/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, f<double> (x=12.300000000000001) at ./gdb_tmpl.cpp:6
6       std::cout << "In f:" << std::endl;
```

Also, you could disassemble it, just use correct command:

```
(gdb) disass f
No symbol "f" in current context.
(gdb) disass f<double>
Dump of assembler code for function f<double>(double):
   0x0000000100001590 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000100001591 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000100001594 <+4>: sub    $0x40,%rsp
   0x0000000100001598 <+8>: mov    0xa71(%rip),%rdi        # 0x100002010
   0x000000010000159f <+15>:    lea    0x9a0(%rip),%rsi        # 0x100001f46
...
```

Comment: @vsoftco I found a way to get step into command worked, just compile with additional g++ flag: **-fno-weak**

Comment: AWESOME!!!! Thanks a lot, it works now :) This should definitely be documented on gdb official site, I cannot believe no one else develops on OS X anymore :) Anyway, I really appreciate your answer! Btw, your first workaround (setting b f<double>) doesn't work on my side, it says `Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xfc` But the `-no-weak` flag does it!

Comment: @vsoftco, I'm not sure It's kind of feature to be documented. I see you have opened a bug against gdb, please add this information there, it should help in problem investigation.

Comment: Yes, will add it. And I just read on the g++ man page that -fno-weak may be removed, so it is considered a deprecated flag... Hope g++ guys will realize that there's something wrong with g++/OS X combination.